# Разложение на группы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Нужно PCRE регуляркой достать все числа из такой строки

```
(3552214449, 4367, 17164, (128, 26, 12, 23, 0, 54, 230, 82))
```

Написал такую регулярку

```
\(((\d+)\, ){3}\(((\d+), ){7}(\d+)\)\)
```

Но она мне заматчила только

```
 17164, 230, 82
```

Тогда я упростил задачу и попробовал достать только три первых числа

```
\(((\d+)\, ){3}
```

в итоге получил группы

> Full match    0-26    `(3552214449, 4367, 17164,`
>
> Group 1.  19-26   `17164,`
>
> Group 2.  19-24   `17164`

Т.е. оно мне достало только одно третье число. Чего я не учитываю?

Даже вот такая регулярка

```
(\d+\, ){3}
```

Вытаскивает только последнее значение

> Full match    1-26    `3552214449, 4367, 17164,`
>
> Group 1.  19-26   `17164,`

Comment: Сколько круглых скобок в выражении есть - столько и групп на выходе. что бы доставать одними скобками повторы в общем случае требуется цикл на языке где вы используете pcre (ну или специализированная функция, которая делает например массив из всех вхождений)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за разъяснение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, после разъяснения @Mike, было принято решение разбить задачу на две. Вначале проверить строку на соответствие маске

```
^\((\d+\, ){3}\((\d+\, ){7}\d+\)\)$
```

а потом в цикле пробежаться по числам

```
\d+
```

Comment: Я может чего не понимаю, но не проще простой заменой убрать все скобки и пробелы, а потом порезать на массив по запятым?

Comment: @rjhdby нет. Мне нужно не просто достать все цифры, но и проверить всю исходную строку на соответствие маске